# How did "y" come to represent the semi-vowel yod /j/ in French orthography?

Tags: orthography, french

I went down a bit of a rabbit hole trying to work out where the different sounds of the "y" in English came from. I quickly established that the semi-vowel was originally written with a yogh, and later came to be written with a "y" likely from French influence. This just kicks the can down the road, though — how did French came to write yod as "y"?

On the surface it seems fairly obvious since "y" already represented /i/ and so since "i" in the early days also represented both /i/ and /j/, the leap was fairly obvious. But I wonder if people would have suddenly assigned a new meaning to a letter that previously never held that meaning — I mean, we are very familiar with English with the different pronunciations of "c" for instance, but if someone tried to spell an /s/ sound with a "k" I'd think they were mad. So extending a sound represented by one letter to a different letter that represents a different shared sound as the first letter doesn't necessarily make sense to me as an obvious explanation that doesn't need elaborating upon — I mean, it might still be true, but I wouldn't like to just assume it without evidence.

I was looking at French sound changes and I noticed that the modern semi-vowel /j/ seems to have a number of sources — one from unpalatisation of a consonant, and one from lenition of stops. But I was wondering if maybe the different sources of this sound could have motivated initially the use of a different symbol, perhaps "y", to represent one? I don't know when these sound changes happened relative to the establishment of "y" in the orthography of French to mean a semivowel, or indeed enough about French to really spot if there could be a pattern here (though of course even if there was initially a pattern it could easily have been eroded later on).

So have there been any studies on exactly how "y" might have gained this new meaning of the semivowel?

Comment: For an opportunity to expand your research, I'd point out that "y" is the semivowel /j/ (well, or something close to it, it's not phonetically [j] in many cases today and in various dialects) in Spanish as well. Orthographies of different languages have influenced one another in many cases.

Comment: y in native French words is mostly used to spell /j/ when following a digraph that'd normally be spelled with i: roi /rwa/ royal /rwajal/. Historically, it derives from conflating the orthographic sequence ij (itself a graphical variant of ii) with the old letter y that'd have been written very similarly or identically in most scripts. In other words, the sequence went roiial (the first i was part of the digraph oi, the second was /j/) > roijal > royal

Comment: Manuscript y in French cursive is a dotless ij, in fact. (you can see a similar development with word final i that was often written with a long descender (i.e. j) after another vowel also getting conflated with y, so that roi was usually roy in classical French)

Comment: @Eauquidort interesting! Does this apply to words like yeux as well (eg was it ijeux originally?) or was this later expanded by regularisation of the original accident? This definitely seems very plausible for me.

Comment: That's a good question, and I forgot about initial y. In that case, I suspect it was used a way to disambiguate between /j/ and /ʒ/, which could both be spelled i or j.